# Find in python combinations of mutually exclusive sets from a list's elements

Tags: python, algorithm

In a project I am currently working on I have implemented about 80% of what I want my program to do and I am very happy with the results.

In the remaining 20% I am faced with a problem which puzzles me a bit on how to solve.
Here it is:

I have come up with a list of lists which contain several numbers (arbitrary length)
For example:

```
listElement[0] = [1, 2, 3]
listElement[1] = [3, 6, 8]
listElement[2] = [4, 9]
listElement[4] = [6, 11]
listElement[n] = [x, y, z...]
```

where n could reach up to 40,000 or so.

Assuming each list element is a set of numbers (in the mathematical sense), what I would like to do is to derive all the combinations of mutually exclusive sets; that is, like the powerset of the above list elements, but with all non-disjoint-set elements excluded.

So, to continue the example with n=4, I would like to come up with a list that has the following combinations:

```
newlistElement[0] = [1, 2, 3]
newlistElement[1] = [3, 6, 8]
newlistElement[2] = [4, 9]
newlistElement[4] = [6, 11] 
newlistElement[5] = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 9]]
newlistElement[6] = [[1, 2, 3], [6, 11]]
newlistElement[7] = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 9], [6, 11]]
newlistElement[8] = [[3, 6, 8], [4, 9]]
newlistElement[9] = [[4, 9], [6, 11]
```

An invalid case, for example would be combination [[1, 2, 3], [3, 6, 8]] because 3 is common in two elements.
Is there any elegant way to do this? I would be extremely grateful for any feedback.

I must also specify that I would not like to do the powerset function, because the initial list could have quite a large number of elements (as I said n could go up to 40000), and taking the powerset with so many elements would never finish.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, note that this sort of combinations problem comes up a lot.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset - would be the first stop on my documentation digging

Comment: What is the range of possible numbers in the individual elements?

Comment: Marcin: I have not tried something specific, yet I ve been trying to theorize the problem in my head. Been going towards recursive solutions but I am not sure.

Comment: kreativitea: The range of numbers in the typical case is from 1 to 10 numbers but in some (rare) items it can go up to 30 or so...if I remember my data correctly

Comment: synthesizerpatel: I will look at that, thank you. Hope I can make sense of it all fast (as I said, very novice in Python).

Comment: Many thanks to all of you for contributing so much so fast. You are all fantastic and this is a great site. Glad to find this community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method used in the program below is similar to a couple of previous answers in excluding not-disjoint sets and therefore usually not testing all combinations.  It differs from previous answers by greedily excluding all the sets it can, as early as it can.  This allows it to run several times faster than NPE's solution.  Here is a time comparison of the two methods, using input data with 200, 400, ... 1000 size-6 sets having elements in the range 0 to 20:

```
Set size =   6,  Number max =  20   NPE method
  0.042s  Sizes: [200, 1534, 67]
  0.281s  Sizes: [400, 6257, 618]
  0.890s  Sizes: [600, 13908, 2043]
  2.097s  Sizes: [800, 24589, 4620]
  4.387s  Sizes: [1000, 39035, 9689]

Set size =   6,  Number max =  20   jwpat7 method
  0.041s  Sizes: [200, 1534, 67]
  0.077s  Sizes: [400, 6257, 618]
  0.167s  Sizes: [600, 13908, 2043]
  0.330s  Sizes: [800, 24589, 4620]
  0.590s  Sizes: [1000, 39035, 9689]
```

In the above data, the left column shows execution time in seconds.  The lists of numbers show how many single, double, or triple unions occurred.  Constants in the program specify data set sizes and characteristics.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from random import sample, seed
import time
nsets,   ndelta,  ncount, setsize  = 200, 200, 5, 6
topnum, ranSeed, shoSets, shoUnion = 20, 1234, 0, 0
seed(ranSeed)
print 'Set size = {:3d},  Number max = {:3d}'.format(setsize, topnum)

for casenumber in range(ncount):
    t0 = time.time()
    sets, sizes, ssum = [], [0]*nsets, [0]*(nsets+1);
    for i in range(nsets):
        sets.append(set(sample(xrange(topnum), setsize)))

    if shoSets:
        print 'sets = {},  setSize = {},  top# = {},  seed = {}'.format(
            nsets, setsize, topnum, ranSeed)
        print 'Sets:'
        for s in sets: print s

    # Method by jwpat7
    def accrue(u, bset, csets):
        for i, c in enumerate(csets):
            y = u + [c]
            yield y
            boc = bset|c
            ts = [s for s in csets[i+1:] if boc.isdisjoint(s)]
            for v in accrue (y, boc, ts):
                yield v

    # Method by NPE
    def comb(input, lst = [], lset = set()):
        if lst:
            yield lst
        for i, el in enumerate(input):
            if lset.isdisjoint(el):
                for out in comb(input[i+1:], lst + [el], lset | set(el)):
                    yield out

    # Uncomment one of the following 2 lines to select method
    #for u in comb (sets):
    for u in accrue ([], set(), sets):
        sizes[len(u)-1] += 1
        if shoUnion: print u
    t1 = time.time()
    for t in range(nsets-1, -1, -1):
        ssum[t] = sizes[t] + ssum[t+1]
    print '{:7.3f}s  Sizes:'.format(t1-t0), [s for (s,t) in zip(sizes, ssum) if t>0]
    nsets += ndelta
```

*Edit:* In function `accrue`, arguments `(u, bset, csets)` are used as follows:
• u = list of sets in current union of sets
• bset = "big set" = flat value of u = elements already used
• csets = candidate sets = list of sets eligible to be included
Note that if the first line of `accrue` is replaced by
`def accrue(csets, u=[], bset=set()):`
and the seventh line by
`for v in accrue (ts, y, boc):`
(ie, if parameters are re-ordered and defaults given for u and bset) then `accrue` can be invoked via `[accrue(listofsets)]` to produce its list of compatible unions.

Regarding the `ValueError: zero length field name in format` error mentioned in a comment as occurring when using Python 2.6, try the following.

```
# change:
    print "Set size = {:3d}, Number max = {:3d}".format(setsize, topnum)
# to:
    print "Set size = {0:3d}, Number max = {1:3d}".format(setsize, topnum)
```

Similar changes (adding appropriate field numbers) may be needed in other formats in the program.  Note, the [what's new in 2.6](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3101-advanced-string-formatting) page says  “Support for the str.format() method has been backported to Python 2.6”. While it does not say whether field names or numbers are required, it does not show examples without them.  By contrast, either way works in 2.7.3.

Comment: Also, this code does not work for me. It gives me an error at the print command "print "Set size = {:3d},  Number max = {:3d}".format(setsize, topnum)
ValueError: zero length field name in format:.
I am running python 2.6

Comment: @jpwat7: What I can't figure out is what are the three arguments u, bset and cset in your function.

Comment: concept303, I added 2 notes at end of answer re those questions. BTW, if you like this answer better than current accepted answer, feel free to select it instead!  :)

Comment: @jpwat7: I will if it works faster than the one currently selected, as this is the fair thing to do. But I need to test it first. I already corrected the print error myself, but I am trying now to load my data in it and run it (as I said, novice so be patient). Trying to make it use my list...

Comment: @jpwat7: I am still trying. I made the changes you indicated. Now I have a list scenarios=([1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]). I do accrue(scenarios) and expect to get [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4] [[1, 2][3, 4]]. Accrue does execute but I when I print I get a generator object. I know generators dont work like iterables but no further than that. Will keep trying. As I said, complete newbie here, sorry...

Comment: concept303, try `[x for x in accrue(map(set, scenarios))]`  (accrue is expecting scenarios to be a list of sets; I might have diverged from your original specification on the input. Result = [[set([1, 2])], [set([1, 2]), set([3, 4])], [set([2, 3])], [set([3, 4])]] which also looks a little off in form but is ok in its values

Comment: @jpwat7: Thanks. This does work although I will have to manipulate the result a bit to get rid of the set and the parentheses but that should be easy to do. (Done it before through taking its element, converting to strings, removing unwanted chars, then back to integers and to list elements). Will proceed with testing the speed vs the originally accepted method. Thanks again.

Comment: When `[x for x in accrue(map(set, scenarios))]` produces
`[[set([1, 2])], [set([1, 2]), set([3, 4])], [set([2, 3])], [set([3, 4])]]`, the statement `[map(list,x) for x in accrue(map(set, scenarios))]` produces
`[[[1, 2]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[2, 3]], [[3, 4]]]` ie if x is a  list of sets, just say map(list,x) to convert to a list of lists.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a generator:

```
import itertools

def comb(seq):
   for n in range(1, len(seq)):
      for c in itertools.combinations(seq, n): # all combinations of length n
         if len(set.union(*map(set, c))) == sum(len(s) for s in c): # pairwise disjoint?
            yield list(c)

for c in comb([[1, 2, 3], [3, 6, 8], [4, 9], [6, 11]]):
   print c
```

This produces:

```
[[1, 2, 3]]
[[3, 6, 8]]
[[4, 9]]
[[6, 11]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 9]]
[[1, 2, 3], [6, 11]]
[[3, 6, 8], [4, 9]]
[[4, 9], [6, 11]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 9], [6, 11]]
```

If you need to store the results in a single list:

```
print list(comb([[1, 2, 3], [3, 6, 8], [4, 9], [6, 11]]))
```

Comment: sets in python have the built-in function isdisjoint: set(A).isdisjoint(set(B))

Comment: @MaxLi: Right. But is there a built-in way to apply this to a sequence of sets (it should return `True` iff the sets are pairwise disjoint)?

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work fine in a quick test. I will now try with the actual data values I have. Would it work if it had to do this for 40,000 initial list elements? I am not sure I am asking it correctly but what is its complexity?

Comment: @NPE: something like reduce(lambda(x,y): set(x).isdisjoint(set(y)),seq) ?

Comment: @concept303: It looks at all subsets, of which there are `2**n`.

Comment: @concept303: There's no way to avoid iterating over the power set, unless there's something special about your data that you're not telling us. :-) Consider the case where all sets are pairwise disjoint: the output consists of `2**n` entries.

Comment: @NPE I haven't tested this, but the reduce function was made for stuff like this:  `len(reduce(set.intersection,map(set,test))) == 0` I don't think it will handle `isdisjoint` since that particular function returns a boolean and not the set, though...

Comment: @kreativitea: This does something different (it looks for elements that are present in *all sets* rather than in *more than one set*).

Comment: @NPE: The code works fine but seems to hit a wall (time-wise) when going around 25-30 initial list elements. You are right. There is indeed the possibility of the case with all sets being pairwise-disjoint. The only special thing about my data that I can think of is that in the vast majority of list elements, there are common elements. For example, I could have 250 elements with 1 being in 240 of them. I will think harder about specific characteristics of the data that could help simplify the problem.

Comment: @concept303: Please do -- I think that's key to finding an efficient algorithm.

Comment: @NPE: The real-world problem, if this could help is this: There are x regions (think of them as parcels) in a given space. I can combine parcels one with another in several meaningful combinations. 1 with 2, 1 with 3, 1 with 4 and 5 and so on. At the end I have all the acceptable combinations. 
If a parcel participates in one combination, it cannot of course participate in another. So I have found all initial acceptable combinations and now I need to find all those that are mutually exclusive. For example, if I choose [1,2] then [3,5] can also be implemented since parcels 3 and 5 remain free.

Answer (score 4):

The following is a recursive generator:

```
def comb(input, lst = [], lset = set()):
   if lst:
      yield lst
   for i, el in enumerate(input):
      if lset.isdisjoint(el):
         for out in comb(input[i+1:], lst + [el], lset | set(el)):
            yield out

for c in comb([[1, 2, 3], [3, 6, 8], [4, 9], [6, 11]]):
   print c
```

This is likely to be a lot more efficient than the other solutions in situations where a lot of sets have common elements (of course in the worst case it still has to iterate over the `2**n` elements of the powerset).

Comment: This, with the same input as before, went from 63 seconds to 0.0009 seconds. It definitely should be recursion! Thank you so much. The worst case of all pairwise disjoint sets almost never happens in my data and if it does, it is is for cases where the initial elements are very few (1 to 3).

Comment: @concept303: Yes, this should be much more efficient since it avoids looking at a lot of dead ends. 40K lists might still be a bit too much for it though.

Comment: 40k is the most extreme I will have to deal with. Typical case is around 1000. I hope it handles that. I need to load the list and try. Will report!

Comment: Handled 13095 parcels in 125secs. Will put a larger list and leave it running for the night to see if there is a result tomorrow morning. Thank you once again so much. Awesome code! I think this answer should be moved to the top somehow if possible.

Comment: @concept303: It will be automatically moved to the top if/when you accept it (no pressure, just saying :-))

Comment: Managed to handle a list with 43,000 elements but not one with 16,500 elements. I guess it depends on the number of combinations that get eliminated.

Comment: @concept303: Exactly. It's possible to come up with a much, much shorter example for which this code will take a long time (due to its exponential worst-case complexity).

Answer (score 1):

using `itertools.combinations`, `set.intersection` and `for-else` loop:

```
from itertools import *
lis=[[1, 2, 3], [3, 6, 8], [4, 9], [6, 11]]
def func(lis):
    for i in range(1,len(lis)+1):
       for x in combinations(lis,i):
          s=set(x[0])
          for y in x[1:]:
              if len(s & set(y)) != 0:
                  break
              else:
                  s.update(y)    
          else:
              yield x


for item in func(lis):
    print item
```

**output:**

```
([1, 2, 3],)
([3, 6, 8],)
([4, 9],)
([6, 11],)
([1, 2, 3], [4, 9])
([1, 2, 3], [6, 11])
([3, 6, 8], [4, 9])
([4, 9], [6, 11])
([1, 2, 3], [4, 9], [6, 11])
```

Comment: That was somewhat similar to how I I was starting to approach it but you put it in working code for me. Thank you!

Comment: @concept303 update the solution, simplified the code by using `for-else` loop and generator function.

Comment: This seems to work faster than the first answer. Is this possible? For 23 elements I am getting 1min with the first method and 15secs with yours. Hmmm...I added another 2 elements to make it 25 and the time became one minute. So this one also necessarily has an exponential time increase.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [NPE's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13573935/395321), but it's without recursion and it returns a list:

```
def disjoint_combinations(seqs):
    disjoint = []
    for seq in seqs:
        disjoint.extend([(each + [seq], items.union(seq))
                            for each, items in disjoint
                                if items.isdisjoint(seq)])
        disjoint.append(([seq], set(seq)))
    return [each for each, _ in disjoint]

for each in disjoint_combinations([[1, 2, 3], [3, 6, 8], [4, 9], [6, 11]]):
    print each
```

Result:

```
[[1, 2, 3]]
[[3, 6, 8]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 9]]
[[3, 6, 8], [4, 9]]
[[4, 9]]
[[1, 2, 3], [6, 11]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 9], [6, 11]]
[[4, 9], [6, 11]]
[[6, 11]]
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner without employing the itertools package.
Here's your data:

```
lE={}
lE[0]=[1, 2, 3]
lE[1] = [3, 6, 8]
lE[2] = [4, 9]
lE[4] = [6, 11]
```

Here's the one-liner:

```
results=[(lE[v1],lE[v2]) for v1 in lE for v2  in lE if (set(lE[v1]).isdisjoint(set(lE[v2])) and v1>v2)]
```

Comment: But would this produce `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 9], [6, 11]]` as per OP's requirements?

Comment: it builds only (x,y) elements, but as I see now powersets are required, sorry I missed the point

Comment: I made exactly the same mistake when I first read the question :)